# Time out error after setting up HANA studio using landscape file import

Tags: eclipse, hana

When I installed HANA in Eclipse and imported a Landscape file provided by my teammate, I am getting the error. I have attached the image to this post.
Please tell me what should I do to resolve it.

> W1D sapw1ddb00.dir.slb.com 00 - System status cannot be determined 
> SAPControl request failed: Connection timed out: connect 
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

[image: Error just after importing the landscape file]

Comment: It means you cannot connect to this system. You may check connection via `ping` or `telnet`

Answer (score 1):

The "Landscape export file" from HANA Studio contains the list of connections set up in HANA Studio incl. the folder structure.

It does not contain **any** login data.

When HANA Studio is set to refresh the instance status for all instances on startup, it will try to connect to the instances via the *sapcontrol* connection, which requires logon data.
Without this information, the call will fail.

The error message in the question does point to a different issue, though.
There seem to be logon data available (otherwise HANA studio would not have tried the connection), but the *sapcontrol* call timed out.

A common issue can be that the target system is not reachable from the workstation this HANA Studio is running on.

To analyse this issue, the usual network tools like `PING`, `DIG`, `ARP`, and `SSH` can come in handy.

Comment: Hey the first error is resolved. Do u have any idea about Java Error??